# Send file to server derictory over form with user's name

Tags: php

I have a form.html

```
<form action="user.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input type="text" size="40" name="UserCallFile" >
      <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Send"><br>
</form>
```

And user.php

```
<?php
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
   } else {
      echo("Error");
   }
?>
```

I need that user could download file to server which name of this file he written on text input. Ho to do that?

I tried this way

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $_POST["fileName"] . "." . "png");
```

But of course here **"png"** have to be logic with any file extension.
I hope you are understand the idea of problem.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, sorry. If you ask for an access control based on some given string at upload time, then please take a look at database programming, since you need to store that string and at learn how to implement a routing script that controls access to files.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and googled already. And then try to ask about a particular solution/framework or api call, as is I think your question is to broad.

Comment: if an user upload multi files, at last you have one image because they replace on last image!! don't use this way. if you need to do this change $files['filename']['name'] to your session username.

Comment: i added some moments. Can anyone help with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to play with this..

```
  $image = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];


    $dir = "gallery/"; //adjust this correctly, watch for slashes depending on your website config
    $newname = $image['name'];

       if(!@copy($image, $dir . $newname))
       {
       echo 'error';
       }
```

Comment: What is function **@copy** mean?

Comment: Just use my code instead of yours and thats it! '@copy' is used for purpose you just requested - it will "download" image to your server :P Replace your code in your user.php with mine and after a first upload, check for folders where image is uploaded and adjust '$dir' accordingly.